# using NSUInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I edited some code to use a variable instead of a number.

```
NSUInteger *hoeveelChars = [eersteDertigTek length] - 30;
```

I changed

```
substringFromIndex: [eersteDertigTek    length] - 30]
```

to

```
    substringFromIndex: [eersteDertigTek    length] - hoeveelChars]
```

Gives me the error invalid operands to binary expression ('nstuinteger"(aka"nisgned int") and ('nstuinteger"(aka"nisgned int")).

Not sure how to fixe this since I do need to have the - number as a variable is there anyone that knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use

```
NSUInteger hoeveelChars = [eersteDertigTek length] - 30;
```

`NSUInteger` is not a class. See [Foundation Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW71).